# Count the max number of ones in a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lapply

I am doing the next task.

Suppose that I have the next vector.

```
(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
```

I need to extract the next info.

1. the maximum number of sets of consecutive zeros
2. the mean number of consecutive zeros.

FOr instance in the previous vector
the maximum is: 3, because  I have 000   00   0

Then the mean number of zeros is 2.

I am thinking in this idea because I need to do the same but with several observations. I think to implement this inside an apply function.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `rle` for this.  As there are only binary values, we could just apply the `rle` on the entire vector, then extract the `lengths` that correspond to 0 (`!values` - returns TRUE for 0 and FALSE others)

```
out <-  with(rle(v1), lengths[!values])
```

And get the `length` and the `mean` from the output

```
> length(out)
[1] 3
> mean(out)
[1] 2
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try another option using `regmatches`

```
> v <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)

> s <- paste0(v, collapse = "")

> zeros <- unlist(regmatches(s, gregexpr("0+", s)))

> length(zeros)
[1] 3

> mean(nchar(zeros))
[1] 2
```

Comment: I understand your idea but the problem is that I am working with a lot data, I have tried and using paste0 is not efficient, I am working with 4M rows and 12 columns of 1 and zeros